# How to load time in GoodData?

Tags: datetime, gooddata

How can I refer hour of day (HH:) from Date type attribute for which I have uploaded data by the format of yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss from the source? Date attributes seem only to provide date without hour as default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are currently working on new implementation of date dimensions. So to have some solution now, what I suggest you is to follow this steps.

1. Execute MAQL DDL that will create time dimension (only once)
2. Open LDM model -> Import from previously created Model
                                -> Finish manually your model (connect time dimension to the rest of your model)
3. Load Data to Time Dimension (see the comment in the attached example)
4. Transform original date time on input to fit in the Model
                                 -> See the Reformat component in the step 3

[Download full example](https://developer.gooddata.com/downloads/cloud-connect/examples/Time.zip) and go through each step to understand the workflow here. As I said this is kind a workaround. We are working on making this smooth and straightforward. After we launch the new Date dimension implementation, the process will be much more easier.

Feel free to contact me directly if you need any assistance! (tobolka@gooddata.com)

Comment: As of today (August 12th, 2014), there's still no estimate from GoodData as to when this feature will land - so I highly recommend contacting Jiri for help on this!

Answer (score 0):

GoodData's date dimension does not support time by default. You need to load it separately. There was a native support in the CL Tool (that generated datasets with time) and we are working on the new functionality that will support time by default.

Anyway, I'm going to prepare example on how to load it today. I will let you know as soon as possible!

JT